# Ubuntu 12.10 external RAM on old laptop?

Tags: ram

Got this old Fujitsu-Siemens Amilo Pro V2010 on which I run now Ubuntu 12.10. Tried to open the back for adding extra RAM. Unfortunately, the back doesn't go off. So I now was curious if I could just use a memory stick and have it be used via USB-plug as an additional external RAM? How would Ubuntu 12.10 then tie that in?

Comment: The DIMM from this Notebook needs to be replaced from the **top**, not the back. There is no working link here but searching Google for `amilo pro v2010 sodimm` will let you download the support manual from *uk.ts.fujitsu.com* in the first few entries. RAM can not reasonably be made external.

Answer (score 2):

You cna make a USB stick swap, but you would get bad performance. You'll need to format the USB stick. Open Disk Utility by searching for it in the dash.

Enter the entry for the USB stick and delete the partition. Create a new partition there. Set it to be Linux swap. Let it finish. Reboot.

Comment: Note that an USB stick speed is way lower than RAM.